# Parsing scalaz.Validation in Java

Tags: java, scala, scalaz

I have a scala function with the following signature:

```
def getValue: Validation[ Throwable, String ]
```

Now, I want to process in Java the result (say `res`) of calling this function.

I can call `res.isSuccess()` and `res.isFailure()` but how do I extract the underlying `Throwable` or success `String` ?

I tried casting but testing `(res instanceof scalaz.Failure)` results in a `scalaz.Failure cannot be resolved to a type` (the scala and scalaz jars are visible)

Is there a generic way of doing this for `Validation`, `Option`, `Either`, etc... ?

**EDIT** I realize I can probably use a `fold` but that would lead to a lot of ugly boilerplate code in Java (which does not need more). Anything better looking ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Success` and `Failure` are both case classes:

```
final case class Success[E, A](a: A) extends Validation[E, A]
final case class Failure[E, A](e: E) extends Validation[E, A]
```

So you can write the following, for example:

```
import scalaz.*;

public class Javaz {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Validation<Throwable, String> res = new Success<Throwable, String>("test");

    if (res.isSuccess()) {
      System.out.println(((Success) res).a());
    } else {
      System.out.println(((Failure) res).e());
    }
  }
}
```

For `Option` and `Either` you can use the `get` method (after taking the `left` or `right` projection in the case of `Either`).

If at all possible it's probably cleaner to do this kind of unwrapping with a `fold`, etc. on the Scala side, though.